# JavaFX - Overlapping panes

Tags: javafx, layer, overlap, pane

I'm trying to find a solution where a layer can overlap an other layer without pushing it to any direction. Similar like this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html but in JavaFX.

It's seems like a very basic feature, but I can't really find a solution.

**What I would like to achieve is something like the following:**

I would like a root `Node`, let's say a `BorderPane`, which in its `left` there is a (settings) `pane` and in its `center` the main content. When the user clicks on a button in the `center`, the `left` pane is showing up without pushing the `center` pane to the right. And that is the problem, because the desired behavior would be to be OVER the centered content not next to it.

`toFront` and `toBack` functions at first glance seemed like a possible solution, but it only changes rendering order.

Unfortunately, I don't think the problem can be done with a `BorderPane` as it can't manage overlapping. But let's hope I'm wrong here. It's not mandatory to achieve this with a `BorderPane`. It's enough if it works similar that I mentioned in the above section.

Maybe it can be achieved with a `SubScene`, but I can't really know how.

*`SubScene` documentation:* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:** Example image

[image: Example image]

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but have you seen this _Stack Overflow_ question: [How to solve the overlapping of the controls each other belonging to two different panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837529/how-to-solve-the-overlapping-of-the-controls-each-other-belonging-to-two-differe)

Comment: It would be a possible solution if the right content pane would not push the main content's pane to the left when it is "opened".  I would like to achieve overlapping. The problem is whenever one of the pane is resized it pushes the other one as well.

Comment: Can't you use a StackPane and set the alignment of your overlapping node to CENTER_RIGHT and also use toForth()? Or maybe a BorderPane at CENTER in which you have your sidebar.

Comment: `BorderPane` may not be the best layout to use for this. I've posted an answer that at least partially does what you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37236961/2991525 A `StackPane` with a margin applied to the background pane equal to the unexpanded size of the menu could take care of resizing a menu and make things a bit simpler than that solution I've thrown together 3 years ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as @Nand & @LBald suggestion, I too think a StackPane could be a good choice in this case. Below is a quick demo to show the overlay node with a little fade effect.

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class OverlayLayout_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Node Overlay Demo");
        primaryStage.show();

        HBox hBox = new HBox(new Button("One"), new Button("Two"));
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        StackPane hPane = new StackPane(hBox);
        hPane.setMaxHeight(100);
        hPane.setVisible(false);
        hPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#55555550");

        VBox vBox = new VBox(new Button("One"), new Button("Two"));
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        StackPane vPane = new StackPane(vBox);
        vPane.setMaxWidth(100);
        vPane.setVisible(false);
        vPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#55555550");

        Button left = new Button("Left");
        Button top = new Button("Top");
        Button right = new Button("Right");
        Button bottom = new Button("Bottom");
        VBox buttons = new VBox(left, top, right, bottom);
        buttons.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;");
        buttons.setSpacing(10);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        StackPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(15));

        StackPane content = new StackPane(buttons);
        content.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            Node node = vPane.isVisible() ? vPane : hPane;
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), node);
            ft.setOnFinished(e1 -> node.setVisible(false));
            ft.setFromValue(1.0);
            ft.setToValue(0.0);
            ft.play();
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(content, hPane, vPane);

        Stream.of(left, top, right, bottom).forEach(button -> {
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                vPane.setVisible(false);
                hPane.setVisible(false);
                Node node;
                switch (button.getText()) {
                    case "Left":
                    case "Right":
                        node = vPane;
                        StackPane.setAlignment(vPane, button.getText().equals("Left") ? Pos.CENTER_LEFT : Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                        break;
                    default:
                        node = hPane;
                        StackPane.setAlignment(hPane, button.getText().equals("Top") ? Pos.TOP_CENTER : Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                }
                node.setVisible(true);
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), node);
                ft.setFromValue(0.0);
                ft.setToValue(1.0);
                ft.play();
            });
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `Pane` to take care of the main content and the config overlapping pane, and then adds a listener in the main content that changes the visibility of the config pane.

```java
Pane container = new Pane();
Pane mainContent = ... ; 
// you main content pane stuff
Pane config = ... ;
// your config pane stuff
container.getChildren().addAll(mainContent, config); // in this order
mainContent.setOnMouseClicked(e -> config.setVisible( ! config.isVisible()) );
```